CKEditor5 configuration options
CKEditor4 allowed a default configuration to be set in a main configuration file, has this feature been removed in CKEditor5? Must all config options be now set in each instance?
The following works:
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '.editor' ), {
        // Editor configuration.
        toolbar: {          
            shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
        }       
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );  

But this means having to set options every time I call .create, is there any other method to set config values as default in CKEditor5?
